# Not enough memory in 32 bit version of VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have write some code to generate a report in excel. During the development process I used 64 bit of windows and 64-bit version of Excel. The code can run perfectly, but my users they use 32-bit of Windows and Excel. These bring about the error "`Not enough memory`". My code some `For..Loop` functions and Array. I tried to figure out the problems by not using Arrays. but it still not work and the same error still occur. Do you have suggestions?

My Excel file and data set is available [on Github here](https://github.com/cmajorros/Allocate-VBA-Report-).  The error file name `Report_Generate.xlsm` nd the data source of the report name `Risk_Loss_Report.xlsm`

Here is the part where I get an error. Please note that this part of code can run well on Excel `64 bit` version. **The memory problem occurs in Excel `32 bit`.**

```
Sub Allocate(LET_NEU, NEU)

    Dim Info As String
    Info = NEU
    Dim LetData As String
    LetData = LET_NEU
    Dim i As Integer

    'Check total record of sheet . If >= 2 record , do
    Dim TotalRecord As Integer
    TotalRecord = Worksheets(Info).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    If TotalRecord >= 2 Then
        Dim R As Integer
        For R = 2 To TotalRecord
            'Check Dept
            Dim deptCurrent As String
            Dim deptPrevious As String
            deptCurrent = "AV" & R
            deptPrevious = "AV" & R - 1
            Dim DeptCurVal As String
            Dim DeptPreVal As String
            DeptCurVal = Sheets(Info).Range(deptCurrent)
            DeptPreVal = Sheets(Info).Range(deptPrevious)
            If DeptCurVal <> DeptPreVal Then
                'Create header
                Dim RinLet As Integer
                Windows("Total Event By Department.xlsx").Activate

                Sheets(LetData).Select
                Dim countmerge As Integer
                Sheets(LetData).Range("A:A").Select
                countmerge = ActiveCell.MergeArea.Cells.Count

                RinLet = Sheets(LetData).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

                Dim DeptTH As String
                Dim RLOS As String
                Dim RLOS_Email As String
                Dim RangeDept As String
                RangeDept = "BG" & R
                DeptTH = Sheets(Info).Range(RangeDept).Value
                Dim RangeRLOS As String
                RangeRLOS = "BA" & R
                RLOS = "ª×èÍ¼Ùé»ÃÐÊÒ¹§Ò¹¤ÇÒÁàÊÕèÂ§ (RLOs) :" & Sheets(Info).Range(RangeRLOS).Value
                Dim RangeRLOS_Email As String
                RangeRLOS_Email = "BB" & R
                RLOS_Email = "Lotus Notes :" & Sheets(Info).Range(RangeRLOS_Email).Value

                '....................................................
                Windows("Total Event By Department.xlsx").Activate
                Sheets(LetData).Select
                Sheets(LetData).Range("A:A").Select
                countmerge = ActiveCell.MergeArea.Cells.Count

                RinLet = Sheets(LetData).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

                'Format Header
                Dim RDept As String
                Dim NumCal As Integer

                RDept = "A" & RinLet + 1

                Sheets(LetData).Range(RDept).Value = DeptTH
                Dim MergeA As String
                MergeA = RDept & ":C" & RinLet + 1
                Dim MergeD As String
                MergeD = "D" & RinLet + 1 & ":G" & RinLet + 1
                Dim MergeH As String
                MergeH = "H" & RinLet + 1 & " :AS" & RinLet + 1
                Sheets(LetData).Select
                Sheets(LetData).Range(MergeA).Select
                With Selection
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .WrapText = False
                    .Orientation = 0
                    .AddIndent = False
                    .IndentLevel = 0
                    .ShrinkToFit = False
                    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                    .MergeCells = True
                End With
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 49407
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With

                Sheets(LetData).Range(MergeD).Select
                With Selection
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .WrapText = False
                    .Orientation = 0
                    .AddIndent = False
                    .IndentLevel = 0
                    .ShrinkToFit = False
                    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                    .MergeCells = True
                End With

                With Selection.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 49407
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With

                Sheets(LetData).Range(MergeH).Select
                With Selection
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .WrapText = False
                    .Orientation = 0
                    .AddIndent = False
                    .IndentLevel = 0
                    .ShrinkToFit = False
                    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                    .MergeCells = True
                End With

                With Selection.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 49407
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With

                ' Add Value to Info to Header
                Dim RRLOS As String
                RRLOS = "D" & RinLet + 1
                Sheets(LetData).Range(RRLOS).Value = RLOS
                Dim RRLOS_Email As String
                RRLOS_Email = "H" & RinLet + 1
                Sheets(LetData).Range(RRLOS_Email).Value = RLOS_Email

                ' Copy detail
                Dim CopyRange2 As String
                CopyRange2 = "A" & R & ":AS" & R
                Dim LetRow As String
                LetRow = "A" & RinLet + 2 & ":AS" & RinLet + 2
                Worksheets(LetData).Range(LetRow).Value = Worksheets(Info).Range(CopyRange2).Value

            Else
                'Copy Detail
                Dim RLet2 As Integer
                RLet2 = Sheets(LetData).Cells(Sheets(LetData).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                Dim RangeNEU As String
                RangeNEU = "A" & R & ":AS" & R
                Dim LetRow2 As String
                LetRow2 = "A" & RLet2 + 1 & ":AS" & RLet2 + 1
                Worksheets(LetData).Range(LetRow2).Value = Worksheets(Info).Range(RangeNEU).Value

            End If

        Next R

    End If

    'Windows("Risk_Loss_Report.xlsm").Activate
    'ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) This is why development requires testing against likely client machine specifications. Gather this info in advance of development and then test before release, especially as you may need to write code to handle the different specs 2) This could well be a non code related issue related to the 32 versus 64 bit and then there are a whole load of articles about workbook optimizations. Look for memory sucking operations like manipulating large amounts of data in memory through data models,  large numbers of pivottables with different caches , images....3) User might have a low memory machine

Comment: Note the exact warning message issued and add to the question.

Comment: please indent your code properly, i struggled to even find your loop. You may also want to run sections of your code to see if you can nail down any code -related problem areas.

Comment: A wild guess - try saving your file after each time round the loop; perhaps that will help flush memory? Also try `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` as perhaps a lot of graphic components are being cached.

Comment: get rid of all your `.Select` and `With Selection`. Work with Ranges instead.

Comment: Also you `Dim` a ton of variables *inside a loop* - very bad practice. Move your `Dim`s where they belong - to the declaration section. I am currently restructuring your code and ridding it of these buggers. Will post soon.

Comment: Have you heard about the free Smartindenter ? http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/

Comment: Lesson: **To avoid problems like this, *always* declare (`Dim`) *all* of your variables at the *beginning* of the procedure.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't changed your logic but I have consolidated all your `Dim`s into the declaration area and removed them from within thre loop. Although you are using way too many variables for my taste, I left them as is.

I also removed all `.Activate` and `.Select` sections. These eat up resources and slow your code down considerably.

Here is your re-worked code, cleaned up and properly indented. Please take a good hard look at the changes.

```
Sub Allocate(LET_NEU, NEU)

Dim Info As String
Dim LetData As String
Dim i As Integer, TotalRecord As Integer, R As Integer
Dim deptCurrent As String, deptPrevious As String, DeptCurVal As String, DeptPreVal As String
Dim RinLet As Integer, countmerge As Integer
Dim DeptTH As String, RLOS As String, RLOS_Email As String, RangeDept As String
Dim RangeRLOS As String, RangeRLOS_Email As String
Dim RDept As String, NumCal As Integer
Dim MergeA As String, MergeD As String, MergeH As String
Dim RRLOS As String, RRLOS_Email As String
Dim CopyRange2 As String, LetRow As String
Dim RLet2 As Integer, RangeNEU As String, LetRow2 As String
Dim wBook As Workbook

Info = NEU
LetData = LET_NEU

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Check total record of sheet . If >= 2 record , do

TotalRecord = Worksheets(Info).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
If TotalRecord >= 2 Then
    For R = 2 To TotalRecord
        'Check Dept
        deptCurrent = "AV" & R
        deptPrevious = "AV" & R - 1
        DeptCurVal = Sheets(Info).Range(deptCurrent)
        DeptPreVal = Sheets(Info).Range(deptPrevious)
        If DeptCurVal <> DeptPreVal Then
            'Create header
            Set wBook = Windows("Total Event By Department.xlsx").ActiveSheet.Parent
            countmerge = wBook.Sheets(LetData).Range("A:A").MergeArea.Cells.Count

            RinLet = Sheets(LetData).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count


            RangeDept = "BG" & R
            DeptTH = Sheets(Info).Range(RangeDept).Value
            RangeRLOS = "BA" & R
            RLOS = "ª×èÍ¼Ùé»ÃÐÊÒ¹§Ò¹¤ÇÒÁàÊÕèÂ§ (RLOs) :" & Sheets(Info).Range(RangeRLOS).Value
            RangeRLOS_Email = "BB" & R
            RLOS_Email = "Lotus Notes :" & Sheets(Info).Range(RangeRLOS_Email).Value
            '....................................................
            Set wBook = Windows("Total Event By Department.xlsx").ActiveSheet.Parent
            countmerge = wBook.Sheets(LetData).Range("A:A").MergeArea.Cells.Count

            RinLet = Sheets(LetData).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

            'Format Header

            RDept = "A" & RinLet + 1

            Sheets(LetData).Range(RDept).Value = DeptTH

            MergeA = RDept & ":C" & RinLet + 1
            MergeD = "D" & RinLet + 1 & ":G" & RinLet + 1
            MergeH = "H" & RinLet + 1 & " :AS" & RinLet + 1

            With Sheets(LetData).Range(MergeA)
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = True
            End With
            With Sheets(LetData).Range(MergeA).Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 49407
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

            With Sheets(LetData).Range(MergeD)
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .WrapText = False
                    .Orientation = 0
                    .AddIndent = False
                    .IndentLevel = 0
                    .ShrinkToFit = False
                    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                    .MergeCells = True
            End With
            With Sheets(LetData).Range(MergeD).Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 49407
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

            With Sheets(LetData).Range(MergeH)
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .WrapText = False
                    .Orientation = 0
                    .AddIndent = False
                    .IndentLevel = 0
                    .ShrinkToFit = False
                    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                    .MergeCells = True
            End With
            With Sheets(LetData).Range(MergeH).Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 49407
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

            ' Add Value to Info to Header
            RRLOS = "D" & RinLet + 1
            Sheets(LetData).Range(RRLOS).Value = RLOS
            RRLOS_Email = "H" & RinLet + 1
            Sheets(LetData).Range(RRLOS_Email).Value = RLOS_Email

            ' Copy detail
            CopyRange2 = "A" & R & ":AS" & R
            LetRow = "A" & RinLet + 2 & ":AS" & RinLet + 2
            Worksheets(LetData).Range(LetRow).Value = Worksheets(Info).Range(CopyRange2).Value

        Else
            'Copy Detail
            RLet2 = Sheets(LetData).Cells(Sheets(LetData).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            RangeNEU = "A" & R & ":AS" & R
            LetRow2 = "A" & RLet2 + 1 & ":AS" & RLet2 + 1
            Worksheets(LetData).Range(LetRow2).Value = Worksheets(Info).Range(RangeNEU).Value
        End If
    Next R
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```